# How to join n lists in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get one big list from this:

```
import numpy
import itertools
N = numpy.array(input().strip().split(" "),int)
N = list(N)
k = len(N)
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sorted(N), i)):
        print(sum(list(j)))
```

There is a number C which is given.
I am to count how many summed permutations of list N (N is given) are equal to number C.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Input, Output?

Comment: your code contains syntax errors. Fix them and describe expected behavior of your code

Comment: I would like to have a list of all the sums from N (N is a list given) and then compare all those sums with a number (again the number is given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to append

```
import numpy
import itertools
N = numpy.array(input().strip().split(" "),int)
N = list(N)
k = len(N)
res = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sorted(N), i)):
        res.append(sum(list(j)))
```